# Need Forward seek button in JW Player

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwplayer

I am using JW Player to play a video, but it is not auto displaying forward seek button, Is there any way I can directly add that button using JW player I need that button just after backward seek.
I have added both the files I am using to play the video

```
**JWPlayer.js**
`import React,{useEffect, useRef} from 'react'
const JwPlayer = ({ video}) => {
    const playerRef = useRef(null);
    const playerInstanceRef = useRef(null);
    useEffect(() => {
      if (playerRef.current && typeof window !== "undefined") {
    playerInstanceRef.current = window.jwplayer(playerRef.current);

    playerInstanceRef.current.setup({
          file: video,
          width: '100%',
          height: "auto",
          aspectratio: '16:9',
          controls: true,
        });
        return () => {
          playerInstanceRef.current.remove();
        };
      }
    }, [video]);

  return (
    <div ref={playerRef}></div>
  )

} 
export default JwPlayer`




`**PlayVideo.js**
import React from 'react'
import JwPlayer from '@/components/JwPlayer'

const PlayVideo = () => {

  return (
    <JwPlayer
    video="Path of video"
    />
  )
}

export default PlayVideo`
type here
```

*Can you help me how should I get forward seek button from JW player it self without manually adding the button?*
JW Player version: 8.30.0

I have tried reading JW Player docs, but did not able to find anything

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are solutions in the comments under this issue.

https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer/issues/3894